# Is there a way to config high chart Y Axis label to appear larger?

Tags: highcharts

I have been using Highchart to create widgets. Is there a way to config high chart Y Axis label to appear larger?

Here is what I have right now, and it would be nicer if the "✔️" and "×" are larger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the font size...

```
 yAxis: {
     labels: {
         style: {
             fontSize:'20px'
         }
     }
 }
```

or if you want more freedom

```
 yAxis: {
     labels: {
         formatter: function () {
             return '<span style="font-size:20px">' + this.value + '</span>';
         }
     }
 }
```